# Get file name on drag and drop FileReader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

Hi I am using native HTML5 drag and drop to upload files to the server. I want to get the name of the file being uploaded from the local system. I am unable to get the name of the file being dropped in the drop zone. Below is the code i have tried. Any help would be appreciated

```
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var childrenDivs = document.getElementById("holder").children
        var temp    
        if(childrenDivs.length > 0){

            var lastDiv = childrenDivs[childrenDivs.length - 1]
            temp = parseInt(lastDiv.id.split("_")[1]) + 1
        }else{

            temp = 1
        }
      var imageDiv = document.createElement('div')
      imageDiv.id = "uploadedImage_"+temp
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = event.target.result;
      console.log(event.target.fileName)
```

instead of `console.log(event.target.fileName)` i have also tried `console.log(event.target.files[0].name)` and `console.log(event.dataTrasfer.files[0])`. Could anyone please help me out here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where are you calling reader.readAs... method?

AFAIK, the proper place to get the filename would be where you register the drop event of a dom element.

```
element.ondrop = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        ....
    }

    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    // can get the name of the file with file.name
    console.log(file.name);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that ... am still a newbie in javascript .... got what i wanted for now ....